# expires.url configuration for static images in lighttpd

Tags: lighttpd, mod-expires

I am trying to avoid repeated re-loading of images from my web app.
I use **lighttpd** to serve the static content, and I have expired configured like so:

***expire.url  = ( "/static/" => "access 1 years", "/static/images/" => "access 1 years")***

This seems to be working for js and css, who live in /static.

**But this does not really work for image files - it seems that the browser still requests them over and over again, receiving a '304 Not Modified' response.**

Help anyone?

Relevant info:

```
**ResponseHeaders:**

Expires : Tue, 22 Jun 2010 13:07:38 GMT
Cache-Control : max-age=31104000
Last-Modified : Thu, 25 Jun 2009 13:00:11 GMT
Date: Sat, 27 Jun 2009 13:07:38 GMT

**RequestHeaders**:

If-Modified-Since:Thu, 25 Jun 2009 13:00:11 GMT
Cache-Control:max-age=0
```

Answer (score 0):

thats completely normal. Serving a http 304 with no body is still a lot faster than serving the whole image/file again.